# heroku godaddy domain java stack SSL setup

Tags: java, ssl, heroku, cedar

I'm trying to set up SSL for my heroku java app. I've followed http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl to setup SSL at secure.mydomain.com. Everything works great if I do https://secure.mydomain.com. But,

1) How do I forward all http traffic to https? Can someone share sample code to do so? i.e. if I go to http://secure.mydomain.com, it should forward me to https://secure.mydomain.com.

2) I've the certificate for secure.mydomain.com only. Can I setup CNAME for www.mydomain.com in godaddy to forward all my traffic to https://secure.mydomain.com.

In short, I'd like to all requests to mydomain.com, www.mydomain.com and secure.mydomain.com to forward to https://secure.mydomain.com.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What framework are you using? Jetty embedded? Spring MVC compiled to WAR + Tomcat/Jetty runner? Other?

Comment: Ditto Jesper.  Heroku doesn't provide a facility to do this.  You need to do it at the application level.  So the solution depends on what framework you are using.

Comment: I'm using Spring MVC compiled to WAR + jetty runner..

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this code can be prettied up a bit and it might miss some corner cases but here is a general purpose servlet filter that will redirect all `http` traffic to `https`:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class SecureFilter implements Filter {

    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {}
    public void destroy() {}

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) 
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest hr = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse hs = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        if(req.isSecure() || 
            (hr.getHeader("X-Forwarded-Proto")!=null && 
             hr.getHeader("X-Forwarded-Proto").equals("https"))) {
            chain.doFilter(req,res);
        } else {
            hs.sendRedirect("https://"+
                            hr.getHeader("Host")+
                            hr.getRequestURI()+
                            (hr.getQueryString()!=null? "?"+hr.getQueryString():""));
        }
    }
}
```

Add it to your app by inserting the following in `web.xml`:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SecureFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>SecureFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SecureFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```